# Why is UILabel 0x0?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uilabel

I'm loading a nib as:

```
ContentViewController *theController = [[ContentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContentView" bundle:nil];
```

which has a label on it.  The view controller has an IBOutlet of UILabel with a @property of retain and synthesized variable.  When I load the nib as above from another class and reference the label's text property as:

```
theController.myLabel.text = @"testing...";
```

myLabel has the address of 0x0.  Before assignment, text is "invalid".  After assignment, it's type is ContentViewController.  There's some issue with memory management.  Any ideas?

Comment: In what method of ContentViewController do you call theController.myLabel.text = @"testing..."; ?

Comment: I don't call it in ContentViewController.  It is being doing in the app's main viewcontroller class.  This is a view based app.

Comment: I've created a new view based app, added another xib with controller and have the same problem.

Comment: If I create a string property on ContentViewController and assign there, then assign that to the label outlet in viewDidLoad of ContentViewController, all is well.

Answer (score 3):

The connections aren't made immediately in the init call.  The main view isn't loaded until the view controller's `view` property is accessed, which causes all of your other IBOutlets to be set as well.  If you are trying to access an IBOutlet before the view is loaded, it will be nil.  Generally, assignment code should go into `-viewDidLoad`.  If you need to do something before adding the view to the screen, just access the view before assigning anything to any of the IBOutlets:

```
theController.view;
theController.myLabel.text = @"testing...";
```

Answer (score 0):

ViewControllers only load their views on demand.  The implicit `getMyLabel` call in the assignment causes the view to be loaded and the outlet to be connected.  As for the type error, I don't know why `myLabel` would end up with a type of `ContentViewController`.  You should check the connections in interface builder and make sure they're hooked up properly.

Comment: Outlets are connected properly.  After above assignment, myLabel is still 0x0.

Answer (score 0):

Is u write any code in ,

```
-(void)loadView {  }
```

method?

If so the IBOutlet object is not getting allocated.
Try commenting this function.
And If u need this function getting fired call loadNibnamed: method for calling that viewController.